# Function notation in words

Tags: functions

My function is $f(x)=x(x-4)(x-2)(x+2)$ and I need to know how to put it into words. My math teacher told me how to put it in words and I've completely forgotten. I've looked everywhere and can not find an answer.

Comment: What do you mean "put into words"?

Comment: I mean it as in actually written out into words; spelling out numbers and saying function of x rather than f(x).

Answer (score 1):

You can say f of x equals x times the quantity x minus 4 times the quantity x minus 2 times the quantity x plus 2. Also you can try "Speak" function in Mathematica and I think it pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)$, you say, "$f$ of $x$".

Comment: What about the parenthesis? What do I do about those?

Comment: When you write $f(x)$, you say $f$ of $x$.  In common mathematical parlance, that indicates you are using a function and that parens need to be present. Were you to write $f(2x + 4)$, you would say, "$f$ of $2x + 4$."

Comment: Wouldn't you say "$f$  of the quantity $2x+4$"? How would you say $f(2x)+4$?

Comment: $f$ of $2x$, plus 4, or 4 plus $f$ of $2x$

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but I would say something along the lines of: 'The function f of x defined by x times the quantity x - 4 times the quantity x - 2 times the quantity x + 2'

Answer (score 0):

"Putting a function into words" is not some magical operation that produces a single correct answer. The point is that if you understand how a function obtains an output from a given input, you should be able to describe this procedure, clearly and precisely, as an English sentence.

For example, if $f(x) = 2x + 3$, you could say "$f$ multiplies $x$ by two and then adds three", or you could say "$f$ is two times $x$ plus $3$".

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ of $x$ is defined by the product of these four terms/quantities: $x$, $x$ minus $4$, $x$ minus $2$, (and finally) $x$ plus $2$.

If you have to read them out aloud, you could pause a little between each of the terms, to mark them as separate. Moreover, $f(x)$ is usually spoken as: $f$ of $x$.